# Как записать псевдоним для типа из traits?

Tags: c++, c++11

Я пытаюсь создать вектор с объектами типа берущегося из traits, но получаю ошибки компиляции. Вот мой код:

```
struct arch32 {};
struct arch64 {};

template<typename Arch>
struct header_traits;

template<>
struct header_traits<arch32>
{
    uint32_t VirtualAddress_type;
};

template<>
struct header_traits<arch64>
{
    uint64_t VirtualAddress_type;
};

/// skiped more lines

template<typename Arch>
using VirtualAddress_t = typename header_traits<Arch>::VirtualAddress_type;

std::vector<VirtualAddress_t>  readData()
{
    std::vector<VirtualAddress_t>  result;
    return result;
}
```

На этот кусок кода получаю ошибки:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'VirtualAddress_type'
error C2065: 'VirtualAddress_t' : undeclared identifier
error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'VirtualAddress_t' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Мне не совсем понятно, а можно ли такое? И если да, то как?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут забыли `;`:

```
struct arch32 {}
struct arch64 {}
```

А тут не тип объявляется, а переменная:

```
template<>
struct header_traits<arch32>
{
    uint32_t VirtualAddress_type;
};
```

Такое объявление:

```
template<typename Arch>
using VirtualAddress_t = typename header_traits<Arch>::VirtualAddress_type;
```

подразумевает такое использование:

```
VirtualAddress_t<Type> var;
```

у вас это не так.

`readData()` уже сами переделайте, всё остальное как-то так:

```
struct arch32 {};
struct arch64 {};

template<typename Arch>
struct header_traits;

template<>
struct header_traits<arch32>
{
    using VirtualAddress_type = uint32_t;
};

template<>
struct header_traits<arch64>
{
    using VirtualAddress_type = uint64_t;
};

/// skiped more lines

template<typename Arch>
using VirtualAddress_t = typename header_traits<Arch>::VirtualAddress_type;
```

Или на ideone: http://ideone.com/od9eWx

Comment: Спасибо! Код привел для истории  ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Ответом на мой вопрос является код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct arch32 {};
struct arch64 {};

template<typename Arch>
struct header_traits;

template<>
struct header_traits<arch32>
{
    typedef uint32_t VirtualAddress_type;
};

template<>
struct header_traits<arch64>
{
    typedef uint64_t VirtualAddress_type;
};

template<typename Arch>
using VirtualAddress_t = typename header_traits<Arch>::VirtualAddress_type;

template<typename Arch>
std::vector<VirtualAddress_t<Arch>>  read()
{
    std::vector<VirtualAddress_t<Arch>> result;
    result.emplace_back(0x41344);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto data = read<arch32>();
    std::cout << "Size of Data: " << data.size() << " items";
    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо @Monah Tuk